# API call will not work only first time loading in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a page that calls for an API to get the showtimes. at first, it will call the API, but it won't do the call after that. following is the code where I call the API.

**GetShowtimes** is my my API call

```
const [showData, setShowData] = React.useState([]);

React.useEffect(() => {
  let mounted = true;
  GetShowtimes()
  .then(data =>{
    if(mounted){
      setShowData(data)
    }
})    
  return () => {
    mounted = false
  }
}, [])

const showtimeData = showData.data.showtimeDetails
console.log(showtimeData)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Effect (without any dependencies) by definition will only run when the component gets mounted. It is not recommended to not provide the empty array as dependencies in the useEffect call. This will unnecessarily consume API resources and is a bad practice in general.

If you just want to call the API continuously (again, not recommended) you can use a timeout function and directly call the service inside the useEffect.

```
const [showData, setShowData] = React.useState([]);

React.useEffect(() => {
  let mounted = true;
  
  const timerId = setInterval(() => {
     GetShowtimes()
        .then(data =>{
        if(mounted){
          setShowData(prevData => prevData.concat(data)
        }
  }, 5000); // will run after every 5 seconds


})    
  return () => {
    clearInterval(timerId); // don't forget to clear the interval
    mounted = false
  }
}, [])

const showtimeData = showData.data.showtimeDetails
console.log(showtimeData)
```

Also, you should read a little about the concept of pagination and try to see if it applies to your use case. With pagination, you would only call the API when you need more data.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

that's reasonable, it only calls once the component is mounted,
if you want to call it continuously you can remove [] in second parameter of useEffect, or add a dependency to call API again after dependency changes.

and be careful about using 'showData.data.showtimeDetails' because the first time you are logging that it has no data part or showtimeDetails
you can simply add '?' before each dot to say if it exist's
sth like this: showData?.data?.showtimeDetails
hope it's useful

Comment: can you suggest code snippet?

Comment: still having difficulties after change the code as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

The code you currently have will only fire once when the component is mounted. (Runs the cleanup function when its unmounted). If you want to make the api call everytime the component rerenders, remove the empty `[]` as second parameter.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  let mounted = true;
  GetShowtimes()
  .then(data =>{
    if(mounted){
      setShowData(data)
    }
})    
  return () => {
    mounted = false
  }
})
```

If you want it to fire only when a particular state( lets say for eg. `trigger`) changes, add it to the array

```
   const trigger, setTrigger = useState(); 
   React.useEffect(() => {
          let mounted = true;
          GetShowtimes()
          .then(data =>{
            if(mounted){
              setShowData(data)
            }
        })    
          return () => {
            mounted = false
          }
        }, [trigger])
```

This will run this useEffect on mount and everytime the `trigger` state changes.Change the value of `trigger` to run the api whenever you need. Let me know if it helps